# Is it okay to use PCA then with LSTM

Tags: pca, model-selection, lstm

I am currently trying to see if there is any validity to this procedure:

1. Using PCA on data in tabular data
2. Then transforming the new "PCA data" into a multivariate time series
3. Using an LSTM to make classification predictions

I have been trying to look for papers using this method, but I only found a few that used this method (they weren't bad, just not the most convincing).

So if anyone has some experience using a similar method or knows some good papers that they can recommend to me that would be much appreciated.

Thanks in Advanced,